# On maximum number of perfect matchings in a graph of genus $g$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, matching-theory

1. What is the maximum number of perfect matchings a graph of genus $g$ can have?
2. What is the maximum number of perfect matchings a bipartite graph of genus $g$ can have?
3. What is the maximum number of perfect matchings a $k$-partite graph of genus $g$ can have?

Comment: Thats 3 questions not one

Comment: @Alex if you noticed 3 subsumes 1 and 2 and therefore there is only 1 real question